# Having an include statement in Asp.Net code

Tags: asp.net, include

I am trying to populate a string with some information from an include file and I'm not quite sure how I should go about doing this

Here's what i've got

```
someText = "text <!--#include file='/includes/myfile.aspx'--> text"
```

Can this be done?

At the moment it is just putting nothing in there

Thanks

Comment: Is that a string in Javascript or a string in the server code?

Comment: That's a string in the Asp.Net code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use an include inside a string.

Just load the contents from the file:

```
someText =
  "text " +
  File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/includes/myfile.aspx")) +
  " text";
```

Comment: I would still strongly recommend that you use a user control - you seem to be using a classic ASP approach to a problem that ASP.NET already has a solution for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to be using a UserControl there.

See here: [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this with ASP.NET. It depends if you have logic in the `myfile.aspx` or not which way would be the best way to go.

Comment: I use the include on loads of different pages - we update this include regularly so would like to still use it - is there not a way around it?

Comment: All that's in the include is HTML `<p></p>` tags